# Composite foreign key as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am currently migrating EF Core 3.0 code-first entity to clean architecture approach.

In EF Core 3.0 this works fine:

```
namespace SmartCom.Models
{
    public class branch
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public virtual string CompanyId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string AddressId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public int RefNo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
        public address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At the DB context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<branch>()
  .HasKey(c => new { c.CompanyId, c.BranchId });
```

With clean architecture, I separated entity business logic from persistence as follows:

1. Business logic model without persistence settings;

```
namespace SmartComCA.CoSec.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Branch
    {
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int RefNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. Persistence configuration in Infrastructure project:

```
namespace SmartComCA.CoSec.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configuration
{
    public class BranchConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Branch> builder)
        {
            //builder.HasKey(t => new { t.Company, t.Address});

            builder.HasOne(t => t.Company).WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("CompanyId");

            builder.HasOne(t => t.Address).WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("AddressId");

            builder.ToTable("branch");
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles but fails during add-migration. How do I specify composite foreign key as primary key in clean architecture where persistence is abstracted from business logic?

Comment: Do you really want address to be a part of primary key? Also, where is `BranchId` property in new `Branch` class?

Comment: Yes, a company has many branches and each branch has a unique address.

Comment: Don't do that. This brings unnecessary complexity to your database. If some entity have to refer the branch, that entity table will need to keep all of branch PK fields inside as a foreign key fields. It's better to keep PKs as simple as possible - just use `Company.Id`, `Branch.Id`, and so on. If you need to maintain uniqueness, use unique constraints at database level,

Comment: Can you include the error message from `Add-Migration`?

Comment: Noted. I will use branch.id approach as you suggested. As I could find no way to implement composite foreign key as primary in clean architecture approach. Thank you.

Comment: //builder.HasKey(t => new { t.Company, t.Address});
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Branch' requires a primary key to be defined.If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

Comment: @ShHueNga there is no `clean architecture approach`. That's just a brand name used by a specific author to promote a book containing more or less common practices. Nothing more. Don't follow any advice blindly without understanding what it means, what it does and what the implications are. Next thing you know you'll be implementing the *generic repository* **antipattern** and start wondering why you need extra transactions or why your `Delete` method resulted in 42 INSERTs

Comment: @ShHueNga in any case the phrase `clean architecture` contains no useful information for this particular question. Yes, you can create composite keys. No, you probably shouldn't use them. *UNLESS* you use EF Core 5 and have a many-to-many table, in which case EF Core 5 maps them transparently.

Comment: Even then, it's a *lot* easier to edit relations if you have a specific ID rather than a composite key. Imagine trying to change one of the keys, eg BranchID. Oops, EF will consider it a *new* record instead of an update on an existing record

Comment: It's not clear to me why a composite key would be necessary and how "clean architecture" would stipulate it. If branch is just a junction between Company and Address then `CompanyId` and `AdressId` *could be* a composite PK and there *shouldn't* be a `BranchId`. But (more likely) if Branch is a first-class citizen of your entity model it should have `BranchId` as its singular PK and maybe `CompanyId` and `AdressId` as an *alternate key*. The domain model, if the architecture is really "clean", couldn't care less how you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the explicit properties with [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties). Which you already did indirectly with `HasForeignKey` fluent API, but following is the explicit definition matching the original definition which also correctly configures the max length for string data types:

```
builder.Property<string>("CompanyId")
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(128);

builder.Property<string>("BranchId")
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(128);
```

Then you can define the composite PK using the shadow property names:

```
builder.HasKey("CompanyId", "BranchId");
```

But please note that having shadow PK imposes some limitations/requirements for operations like update and delete, since they would require having the loaded related objects rather than just their keys.

Comment: Using a composite key for a M:N table will create problems if one of the keys has to change. EF Core may not know whether the new combination is a new record or a modified one

Comment: I'm starting to fear the phrase `clean architecture approach`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In EF Core keys of any sort (primary/alternate, simple/composite) are not mutable. It doesn't matter if they are mapped to "real" or shadow properties. The choice of using composite keys with that limitation is up to you. I don't think our goal is to analyze people's design - in this case, they already have that composite key in their original design, so this (un fact EF Core) is just giving them an option to do the same with shadow properties.

Comment: I had web apps in mind, where edits come as detached entities. The key protection can't help there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I don't care about architectural terms. My goal is to provide EF Core data model mapping for their "doman" or whatever they call them models when possible. If I have to share opinion, they should really use separate models - one which follows "their" concepts/rules, and one for persistence. And map between the two where needed.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Clean architecture allows persistence and presentation abstraction. One common business logic library for Winforms and Angular 10. Linux, Cloud, Oracle or SQL server. Thank you